# How to bin rows by mean then and compute dispersion to identify outliers

Tags: r

I have a matrix where I want to split all rows into 20 bins according to row means. I can achieve this as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
n_bins = 20
data$bin = ntile(rowMeans(data), n_bins)
```

Now, within each bin, I would like to z-normalize the dispersion measure of all rows within the bin, in order to identify outlier rows. I want to define outliers at having a z-score cutoff of 1.7. I'm not sure if there is an easy way to go about this but I'm currently stuck at this point.

**EDIT:**

Problem re-stated/clarified: I have a data.frame that is rather large with 12374 rows (genes) and 785 columns (cells). I'd like to group rows according to rowMeans into 20 bins. Within each bin, I'd like to z-normalized the dispersion measure (variance/mean) of all genes within that bin in order to identify outlier genes whose expression values were highly variable even when compared to genes with similar average expression. I would then like to extract out genes which exceed a z-score threshold of 1.7 to identify significantly variable genes from each bin.

```
> head(temp[,1:5])
              Drop7_0_AAACTAGGGTGG Drop7_0_AAAGGACGTACG Drop7_0_AACACTTGAGCC Drop7_0_AAGGCAACGAAT Drop7_0_AATGATGGGGTA
0610007P14RIK            0.1439444            0.0000000             0.000000            0.8759335            0.0000000
0610009B22RIK            0.0000000            0.6776718             0.000000            0.0000000            0.0000000
0610009O20RIK            0.1439444            0.0000000             0.000000            0.2735741            0.0000000
0610010B08RIK            1.4769893            1.1369215             1.124842            0.8759335            1.9544187
0610010F05RIK            0.7944809            0.0000000             0.000000            0.7016789            0.9144108
0610010K14RIK            0.1439444            0.0000000             1.124842            0.7016789            0.0000000
```

When I run this code:

```
library(dplyr)
n_bins = 20
temp = data
temp$rowm = rowMeans(temp)
outscore = temp %>% mutate(bin=ntile(rowm,n_bins)) %>% 
  group_by(bin) %>% mutate(zscore=scale(rowm),outlier=abs(zscore)>1.7)
```

I get the error: `Error: dims [product 619] do not match the length of object [618]` which I think refers to the number of bins in the data.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Giving a good reproducible example will help us help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Maybe use `boxplot(..., plot = FALSE)`? Or `hist` for breaks, if you like.

Comment: @Hack-R, I've edited my OP to show a bit of the data I'm working with and the code I have. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @user2117258 Great, thanks for the extra effort. If the current answers don't answer your question I'll take a stab at it.

Comment: @Hack-R, please! Unfortunately I'm still stuck on this problem. I will restate the problem in the OP again for clarification.

Comment: @Hack-R I think that refers to the number of bins (12374/20=618.7) created.

Comment: @user2117258 if you see the `str(outscore)` you can tell that zscore is the whole scale object hence the error. if you replace the last `mutate` for my `ave` solution it will work. see option 3 of my answer

Answer (score 1):

I think I understood your question. Assume that `Species` are you bins already created. You can use `scale` to calculate your standardized scores.

```
     data(iris)
      iris %>% select(Species,Sepal.Length) %>%
 group_by(Species) %>% mutate(zscore=scale(Sepal.Length))
```

you get zscore by bin or this case by Species

```
Species Sepal.Length      zscore
    (fctr)        (dbl)       (dbl)
1   setosa          5.1  0.26667447
2   setosa          4.9 -0.30071802
3   setosa          4.7 -0.86811050
4   setosa          4.6 -1.15180675
5   setosa          5.0 -0.01702177
6   setosa          5.4  1.11776320
7   setosa          4.6 -1.15180675
8   setosa          5.0 -0.01702177
9   setosa          4.4 -1.71919923
10  setosa          4.9 -0.30071802
..     ...          ...         ...
```

from there you can create a flag to highlight those rows gt `abs(1.7)`

**OPTION 2:**

Transpose all your cols to rows and calculate z-score by group.

```
  data(iris)
 w <-  iris %>% select(Species,Sepal.Length:Petal.Length) %>%
   gather(features,values,Sepal.Length:Petal.Length) %>% select(-features)
 w$z <- ave(w$values, w$Species, FUN=scale)
```

**Option 3**

```
 library(dplyr)
 n_bins = 20
 temp = data
 temp$rowm = rowMeans(temp)
 outscore = temp %>% mutate(bin=ntile(rowm,n_bins)) 
 outscore$zscore <- ave(outscore$vrowm, outscore$bin, FUN=scale)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Great, but where is dispersion computed? Also is `scale()` equivalent to computing dispersion across all columns with a row? The way my data is set up is that I have 200 columns and 5001 rows, where the last row is the bin number.

Comment: well you did not specify this in your original question - if you can elaborate a bit more then we can help you better. you calculate the `rowMeans` using `ntile` as per your question and then use `scale`  to get your z-scores using the `group_by` statement

Comment: you can also transpose your 200 cols to rows so the `scale` will work without to much effort. will give you an example soon.

Comment: Added a 2nd option just in case

Comment: Still having issues trying to apply this.  I want to z-normalize the dispersion measure of all rows within the bin and define rows (within each bin) with abs(z-scores) > 1.7. Dispersion in this case is defined as variance/mean.

Comment: I've edited my OP, please have a look! I feel like I'm close but running into issues with the bins.

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand how you're computing dispersions (mean/variance) for each bin. The way I understand your code is that you're binning row means, then scaling the rowmeans. I ultimately want to bin by row means, then scale the dispersions for each bin and identify outliers.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Alton's answer:

```
library(dplyr)

n_bins = 20
#making sample data
data = as.data.frame(rbind(replicate(100,rnorm(1000))))

data$rowm = rowMeans(data)

outscore = data %>% mutate(bin=ntile(rowm,n_bins)) %>% 
  group_by(bin) %>% mutate(zscore=scale(rowm),outlier=abs(zscore)>1.7)
```

`scale` normalizes the distribution of the row means so that the overall standard deviation is 1. "Outliers", in this case with a z-score with magnitude greater than 1.7, are marked in the `outlier` column.

If you want to look at which rows have abnormal variance, you can do something like this:

```
outscore$varscore = apply(outscore[,grepl("^V[0-9]+",names(outscore))],1,var)

outscore = outscore %>% mutate(zscore_var = scale(varscore),
  var_outlier = abs(zscore_var) > 1.7)
```

If you want to use the row mean bins, you can use that grouping, too:

```
outscore$varscore_grouped = outscore %>% group_by(bin) %>% 
  select(.,starts_with('V')) %>% apply(1,var)

outscore = outscore %>% mutate(zscore_var_grouped = scale(varscore_grouped), 
  var_group_outlier = abs(zscore_var_grouped) > 1.7)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I want to z-normalize the dispersion measure of all rows within the bin. Dispersion in this case is defined as variance/mean.

Comment: I added a couple more examples on how to use measure outliers in terms of variance instead of mean.

Comment: I cannot seem to get my row names to appear from outscore. I run into the error: `Error: dims [product 619] do not match the length of object [618]`

Comment: Did you use `rownames(outscore)`?

Comment: I'm not able to make the outscore data frame because of the row names in my initial `data` data frame. Im updating my OP.

Comment: I would greatly appreciate any help you could toss my way!